# Limit SQL Azure access to Roles within the same subscription only

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I would like to limit access to my SQL Azure databases to only roles that are within the same subscription.

It seems the 'Allow other Windows Services to access this server' (0.0.0.0 - 0.0.0.0) rule would allow access attempts from any role within any subscription.

Is there currently any way to limit connection attempts to only my roles? If not what protection does SQL Azure offer against hostile roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to limit connection attempts to only your roles. It's only a "normal" firewall which, when open for "other Windows Services" will open the 1433 port to all Azure services. No way to distinguish by role.

About the protection - I guess the only protection is the default SQL Server Authentication. I cannot say though if there is some auto blocking mechanism for too many wrong password attempts.

Something else - when you create a server, you have a unique server name, which is unique to your account and not other. So in order for the "hostile role" to begin attempting connect to your server, it must first discover your server name. Then your administrator user (which is something you create) or a valid login.